# I have a PHP table that calculates Fahrenheit into Celsius, I need to use Span Class to change color of the Celsius results based on certain criteria

Tags: php, html, class, if-statement, html-table

How can I go about doing this? I know I have to use an if statement, but I have tried placing it everywhere and my code just gets messed up.

The criteria is if the value in C is less than or equal to 0, the result should be blue. If it is greater than or equal to 100 C, it's displayed in red. All other temperatures in C should be green.

This is my table code,

```
<tr>
        <td align="center"><strong>Fahrenheit</strong></td>
        <td align="center"><strong>Celsius</strong></td>
    </tr>

   <?php

   for ($tempFahrenheit = 0; $tempFahrenheit <= 250; $tempFahrenheit++){
   $tempCelsius = (5/9)*($tempFahrenheit-32);
   echo "<tr><td>$tempFahrenheit&degF.</td>";
   echo "<td>$tempCelsius&degC.</td></tr>";   

  }

  ?>
```

EDIT:

this is the if statement code that i was trying to embed in the table

```
if ($tempCelsius >= 0)
{
print("<span class='blue'>" . <td>$tempCelsius&degC.</td></tr> . "</span>     <br>");     
}
```

Comment: This seems like it could be a homework assignment? Even though your `if` statement is messing your code up it's important to see what you've tried in order to really help you learn. Please post your if statement that's not working.

Comment: Your entities are missing the closing semicolons.

Comment: I got frustrated and deleted everything after the errors started showing, all I have is the table code, but I have an if statement code that I was trying to use which didn't really work out too well.

Comment: Your `if` statement doesn't work because your string doesn't end at `<span class='blue'>`. The `<td>` needs to be in quoted. The `$tempCelsius` could then be in double quotes or concatenated. Then the `&degC.</td></tr>` would also be need to be quoted. More information: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well basically:

```
if($tempCelsius <=0){
echo "<td css for BLUE >$tempCelsius&degC.</td></tr>";  

}elseif($tempCelsius <100){
echo "<td css for green >$tempCelsius&degC.</td></tr>";  

}else
echo "<td css for red >$tempCelsius&degC.</td></tr>";  

}
```